# FAB Toolbar - Won't open entire way

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am putting a FAB Toolbar component in the lower right of the screen. It hovers over the scrollable content (emulated here by the `<div>`). The behavior of hovering over the content is correct, and it appears to be correctly placed.

However, the toolbar **does not** expand to its full size. I tried putting the HTML into the `<md-content>`, but that causes the positioning to break. Is there something I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance!

```js
//app.js
angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('BasicDemoCtrl', function DemoCtrl() {
   
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">
</head>

<body ng-app="BlankApp" ng-controller="BasicDemoCtrl" layout="column" ng-cloak>   
    <!-- Page Window -->
    <md-content flex>
        <div style="position:absolute;left:48px;top:115px;width:1507px;height: 500px;"></div>
    </md-content>
     <md-fab-toolbar md-direction="left" class="md-fab-bottom-right">
        <md-fab-trigger class="align-with-text">
            <md-button aria-label="menu" class="md-fab md-primary">
                <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
            </md-button>
        </md-fab-trigger>
        <md-toolbar>
            <md-fab-actions class="md-toolbar-tools">
                <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="reviewTable()">
                    <md-icon>launch</md-icon>
                </md-button>
                <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="showActionToast()">
                    <md-icon>edit</md-icon>
                </md-button>
                <md-button class="md-icon-button">
                    <md-icon>arrow_back</md-icon>
                </md-button>
            </md-fab-actions>
        </md-toolbar>
    </md-fab-toolbar>
     
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Your application bootstrap  -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `FAB Toolbar` component is not fully matching the FAB `button` classes. I was able to get something close to what I wanted with the code below. Essentially, I used the class `.md-is-open` to move the FAB's open toolbar into the right position. This keeps the stylistic position of the FAB in place (`.md-fab-bottom-right`). It is not perfect, and the position changes abruptly on close.

```js
//app.js
angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('BasicDemoCtrl', function DemoCtrl() {
   
});
```

```css
md-fab-toolbar { width: 100vw; }

md-fab-toolbar.md-is-open { right: 0 !important; bottom: 0 !important; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">
</head>

<body ng-app="BlankApp" ng-controller="BasicDemoCtrl" layout="column" ng-cloak>   
    <!-- Page Window -->
    <md-content flex>
        <div style="position:absolute;left:48px;top:115px;width:1507px;height: 500px;"></div>
    </md-content>
     <md-fab-toolbar md-direction="left" class="md-fab-bottom-right">
        <md-fab-trigger class="align-with-text">
            <md-button aria-label="menu" class="md-fab md-primary">
                <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
            </md-button>
        </md-fab-trigger>
        <md-toolbar>
            <md-fab-actions class="md-toolbar-tools">
                <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="reviewTable()">
                    <md-icon>launch</md-icon>
                </md-button>
                <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="showActionToast()">
                    <md-icon>edit</md-icon>
                </md-button>
                <md-button class="md-icon-button">
                    <md-icon>arrow_back</md-icon>
                </md-button>
            </md-fab-actions>
        </md-toolbar>
    </md-fab-toolbar>
     
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Your application bootstrap  -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS

```
.md-fab-toolbar.md-fab-bottom-right {
  width: 100vw;
}
```

Try running the following snippet- notice the `<style>`

```js
//app.js
angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('BasicDemoCtrl', function DemoCtrl() {
   
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">
  <style>
   .md-fab-toolbar.md-fab-bottom-right {
      width: 100vw;
    }
   </style>
</head>

<body ng-app="BlankApp" ng-controller="BasicDemoCtrl" layout="column" ng-cloak>   
    <!-- Page Window -->
    <md-content flex>
        <div style="position:absolute;left:48px;top:115px;width:1507px;height: 500px;"></div>
    </md-content>
     <md-fab-toolbar md-direction="left" class="md-fab-bottom-right">
        <md-fab-trigger class="align-with-text">
            <md-button aria-label="menu" class="md-fab md-primary">
                <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
            </md-button>
        </md-fab-trigger>
        <md-toolbar>
            <md-fab-actions class="md-toolbar-tools">
                <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="reviewTable()">
                    <md-icon>launch</md-icon>
                </md-button>
                <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="showActionToast()">
                    <md-icon>edit</md-icon>
                </md-button>
                <md-button class="md-icon-button">
                    <md-icon>arrow_back</md-icon>
                </md-button>
            </md-fab-actions>
        </md-toolbar>
    </md-fab-toolbar>
     
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Your application bootstrap  -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! That fixed the width issues, but when the toolbar opens, I noticed that the right and bottom borders are not flush with the screen. Is that fixable?

Comment: Yeah..add `right: 0; bottom: 0;` to that stylesheet after width

Comment: I posted my solution improvised off of your suggestions. It seems as if the FAB Toolbar is not fully cross-operational with the FAB (as a md-button)'s styles.